# ActiveRecord: как производится изменение записи в базе данных?

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

Только учусь.
Использую ActiveRecord и Sinatra.
Не могу понять , как изменить данные в таблице.
Можете привести примеры, как это сделать?
пример:

/db/schema.rb :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160616152036) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "name"
    t.text     "surname"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

../db/migrate/20160616152036_create_users.rb:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

def change
    create_table :users do |u|
      u.text :name
      u.text :surname

      u.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

view:

```
    <h2>Save User</h2>
<div>
  <form action="/user/<%= @user.id %>/edit" method="post">
    <input name="user[name]" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Type your name">
    <br/>
    <input name="user[surname]" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Type your last name">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">save</button>
    <button formaction="/" formmethod="get" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

app.rb :

```
set :database, "sqlite3:all_users.db"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
    validates :surname, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
end

get '/user/:id/edit' do


  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  erb :edit
end

post '/user/:id/edit' do

  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.update(name: params[:name], surname: params[:surname])

  erb "<h3>Спасибо, изменения сохранены!</h3>"

end
```

Comment: Ну, Sinatra тут немножко ни при чём, ActiveRecord приблизительно везде работает одинаково. Так же, как и в Rails. И вне веб-фреймворков вообще. Какой именно момент вам неясен?

Comment: @Кнопкатык не получается изменять имеющуюся сущность в БД.

Comment: @Кнопкатык добавил пример в сам пост выше.

Comment: @ToshiDono какие-то сообщения об ошибках выводятся в консоль/лог? Если да, то какие? Попробуйте вместо update использовать update!

Comment: @Кнопкатык Вы имеете ввиду то, что в логе сервера? Если да, то вот запись из него соответствующая нажатию на "save":
`D, [2016-06-17T09:12:59.534286 #4220] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
D, [2016-06-17T09:12:59.534811 #4220] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
D, [2016-06-17T09:12:59.716399 #4220] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2016:09:12:59 +0300] "POST /user/6/edit HTTP/1.1" 200 1854 0.1840
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2016:09:12:59 MSK] "POST /user/6/edit HTTP/1.1" 200 1854
`

Comment: Ну, сохранение начинается и откатывается. Скорее всего, ошибка валидации. Не видя модель, не могу сказать, в чём дело. Рекомендую взять отладчик, остановиться сразу после `update` и глянуть в `@user.errors`.

Comment: @Кнопкатык добавил модель в пост.

Comment: А отладчиком прошлись?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Несоответствующая форма параметров в двух местах

```
@user.update(name: params[:name], surname: params[:surname])
```

Это рассчитывает, что в `params` лежат:

```
{name: 'Имя', surname: 'Фамилия'}
```

...но они там не лежат. И вы сами указали, что параметры должны иметь другую форму:

```
<input name="user[name]" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" ...>
<!--        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
<input name="user[surname]" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" ...>
<!--        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
```

...это конвенция вложенных параметров Rack.

- Ключ вида `a` это одиночное поле `a` в корне параметров.
- Ключ вида `a[b]` преобразуется в поле `b` вложенного мапа `a`.
- Ключ вида `a[][b]` в поле `b` мапа внутри массива `a`.
- Ключ вида `a[]` просто в элемент массива `a`

  - Rack-прослойка, отвечающая за разбор параметров, не перезаписывает поля, когда речь о массивах. Дублирующий ключ считается начинающим новый элемент массива.

Реально в `params` лежит вот такая штука:

```
{ user: { name: 'Имя', surname: 'Фамилия' } }
```

---

*Серьёзно, вооружитесь отладчиком. Очень тяжело жить, не имея способов посмотреть на внутреннее неожиданно ошибочное состояние программы.*

Comment: Отличный ответ. Хоть я и не задавал вопрос, но почерпнул много нового для себя, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Содержание params видно внизу страницы отладки синатры (страница ошибки), строки `sinatra.accept` и `sinatra.error.params`
Если params не содержит значений, отличных от полей таблицы, можно присвоить напрямую; значения, отсутствующие в таблице, не будут присвоены:

- содержимое params:`{"edited"=>{"author"=>"George Orwell", "title"=>"Nineteen Eighty-Four", "year"=>"1949", "tags"=>"d", "comment"=>"a", "spent"=>"on"}, "captures"=>[], "id"=>"1"}`
- поля объекта и связанной с ним таблицы соответствуют хэшу :edited, присваиваем так:`@line_for_edit.update params[:edited]`
- если в хэше лишние данные, обращаемся к ним `params[:edited][:spent]`